# Display inline-flex affecting children?

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a parent div with the `display: inline-flex` property.

The problem is that the children elements are also being aligned inline, despite in css having the `display: block`. How do I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any HTML code or CSS?

Comment: `flex-flow: column nowrap`

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for the answer, it works!

Comment: `flex-flow` have some issues on some browsers so I recommend stay away from that, `nowrap` is the default so no need for that ... do it how I suggest in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex` items are by default `row` items, make them `column` will likely do what you want

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
.parent div {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```